# SQL - Order by issue

Tags: sql

How to add another order by at the end with records sorted by field_id, but order should be in the same way they are set in the IN clause 32015102,32015100,32015101,32015105. The numbers can change and can increase or decrease in count.

```sql
select * from dba.form_data where form_id = 207873 and field_id in (32015102,32015100, 32015101, 32015105 )
order by sub_id, array_number
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MySQL? Oracle? SQL Server? ... Please always tag SQL questions with the DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 1):

An `IN` clause contains an unordered set of values. `IN (1,2,3)` and `IN (3,2,1)` are considered equal.

So you must add some order criteria. In your case you want 32015102 first, 32015100 second, etc. Present the DBMS the values with appropriate sort keys. E.g.:

```
select * 
from dba.form_data fd
join
(
  select 32015102 as value, 1 as sortkey
  union all
  select 32015100 as value, 2 as sortkey
  union all
  select 32015101 as value, 3 as sortkey
  union all
  select 32015105 as value, 4 as sortkey
) criteria on criteria.value = fd.field_id
where fd.form_id = 207873
order by criteria.sortkey;
```

Answer (score 0):

TSQL solution on one of my DBs:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) AS a,
 * FROM (VALUES (21963), (21961), (27665)) AS X(b) 
)

SELECT tpb.AutoId FROM dbo.TPB AS tpb 
JOIN CTE ON CTE.b = tpb.AutoId
ORDER BY CTE.a
```

Step by step:

Row constructor syntax: SELECT * FORM( VALUES (1), (2), (3)) X(a)
Create a table named X with a column a that contains 1, 2,3.

ROW_NUMBER(): I needed row number for final sorting of the array. It needs an over clause so I used dummy OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) which is, well, order by nothing.

Encapsulate this in a CTE, then select from your target table and join it with CTE on your desired order then sort it using corresponding row_numbers.